# Update NestedScrollView layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

Here is my layout:

```
CoordinatorLayout
    NestedScrollView
        LinearLayout
            TextView
            TextView
            TextView
```

If I change the visibility of the textviews (visible/gone) the LinearLayout and the NestedScrollView should change their height but they do only until the next scheduled layout measuring pass.

So for several second the NestedScrollView has an incorrect scrolling height.

How to update the NestedScrollView (scrolling) height when I change the layout's inside the LinearLayout?

Here is xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/filters_detail_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/filter_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title_types"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_tiny"/>

                    ...

                    ...

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @zackygaurav kind of. Instead of using a hidden state for the behavior I collapse the view with 0 pixel collapse height and then set the visibility to gone. If I need to expand it I set the visibility to visible. This will not work if you want a `0<` height in the collapse state and adjustable height. Looks like the behaviors' hidden state does not remeasure the layout